# Expresión regular para validar hash de transacciones en la red de smart chain

Tags: python, regex

Necesito validar un hash de transacciones de criptomonedas en la red de smart chain.
Y para ello necesito usar expresiones regulares o código en Python.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea o recomendación? Ejemplo: `0x0eedc9b71f3c34c973965817deb42270c8b66c3bb4270c34cfe14744574d735a`

0x03d6e94eb821ce53592ddce2bf666c595027399ca0022032a7a3fe099fa252eb

Mi aplicación pide para confirmar la realización de un pago el hash de la transacción, pero antes de recibirlo y almacenarlo en la bd, me gustaría comprobar que al menos la estructura del hash que me están dando es correcta, para a la hora de usar ese dato el programa no tenga problemas

Estos tipos de hash son vistos llamados ‘Txhash’ en por ejemplo las páginas de historiar de transacciones como  bscscan, donde se pude ver como primera columna

Por eso lo ideal sería una expresión regular que lo valide. Me gustaría poder usarla en Python, algo así:

```py
import re
def esUnHashCorrectoEnTransaccion_USDT_BET20(supuestoHash):
    patron=re.compile("^exprecion que necesito$")
    return re.match(patron,supuestoHash)!=None
```

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta parece demasiado amplia para este sitio. Por favor edita tu pregunta a un problema específico. Por ejemplo, ¿qué has intentado? ¿en qué te atoraste? Saludos

Comment: Buenas, gracias por su tiempo, ya la edité, no sé si ahora se entienda mejor

Comment: Bueno, aún parece algo amplia (mejor dicho, parece basada en opiniones). Si nos dieras un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible, sería mucho más fácil darte una mano :)

Comment: Le agregue código a la pregunta esta vez, espero que quede al menos algo mas claro

Comment: Ahhh... ya caigo. Gracias por clarificar.

Comment: Solo una cosa: ¿Es una pregunta de Python o C#? ¿O ambas?

Comment: Puse la etiqueta c# pq no encontraba otra que encajara, pero me sirve igual el código en el idioma que me lo den pq se le básico en varios, incluido el c#, aunque lo ideal sería una expresión regular que sirve para todos

Comment: Entonces, solo buscas una expresión regular, no una solución para un lenguaje en particular?

Comment: estoy usando Python para este proyecto por lo que lo aceptaría mejor la respuesta en Python, pero si, lo que busco es la expresión regular, no necesaria mente la solución para un lenguaje en particular

Comment: Bueno. Edité la pregunta para especificar un poco tu problema. Por ejemplo, considero que algunas etiquetas no hacían falta.

Comment: que etiquetas me recomiendas para esta pregunta?

Comment: Bueno, en mi edición ya las moví, quite algunas. Si quieres revísalas

Comment: como llego a tu edición? Que soy nuevo en la plataforma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un hash, de acuerdo las reglas que se deducen del planteamiento, debe:

1. Comenzar con "0x".
2. Contener 64 caracteres hexadecimales (en minúsculas).

La expresión regular que verifica esa condición es:

```
"0x[0-9a-f]{64}"
```

#### Demo

import re

```
patron = re.compile(r"0x[0-9a-f]{64}")

def validar(hash):
    return patron.match(hash) is not None


hash = "0x03d6e94eb821ce53592ddce2bf666c595027399ca0022032a7a3fe099fa252eb"
print(validar(hash), hash)

malo = "0x03d6e94Xb821ce53592ddce2bf666c595027399ca0022032a7a3fe099fa252eb"
print(validar(malo), malo)
```

produce:

```
True 0x03d6e94eb821ce53592ddce2bf666c595027399ca0022032a7a3fe099fa252eb
False 0x03d6e94Xb821ce53592ddce2bf666c595027399ca0022032a7a3fe099fa252eb

Process finished with exit code
```